# Why is the class of all sets denoted $V$?

Tags: soft-question, notation, set-theory, math-history

In NBG set theory, why is the class of all sets denoted $V$? $S$ seems to me to be the natural designation.

Comment: Dunno. Maybe the V of German "Vereinigung"? Just a guess.

Comment: What's so natural about $S$?

Comment: @bof: Set maybe? Reminds me of papers from the 1960s and 1970s where the power sets was denoted by $S(x)$, presumably for similar reasons (subsets).

Comment: @AsafKaragila The shape of the letter V looks like pictures of $V$ that people draw.

Comment: @bof: True, but also the shape of an Aronszajn tree/the binary tree (i.e. the Cohen forcing), according to Uri Abraham's "classic drawing".

Comment: @AsafKaragila A model of set theory is a directed graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $\in$. :-)

Comment: @bof: That's random! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely source is Giuseppe Peano, [Arithmetices Principia Novo Methodo Exposita (1889)](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog), page viii :

> Signum $\text V$ significat *verum* [...] Signum $\Lambda$ significat *falsum*, sive *absurdum*.

But the same symbols are used by Peano in the "calculus of *classes*" (page xi) :

> Signum $\Lambda$ indicat classem quae nullum continet individuum [i.e. the *empty set*].
>
> Signo $\text V$, quod classem ex omnibus individuis constituam, [i.e. the *universal class*].

---

From Peano, the symbol arrived to Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, [Principia Mathematica, I (2nd ed 1927)](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA216), page 216 :

> The universal class, denoted by $\text V$, is the class of all objects [...] Its definition is as follows :
>
> > *24.01. $\text V = \hat x(x = x)$ Df [in modern symbols : $\text V = \{ x \mid (x = x) \}$].

---

Finally, the current usage is due to Kurt Gödel, [The Consistency of the Axiom of Choice and of the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis With the Axioms of Set Theory (1940)](https://books.google.it/books?id=rXjGFI6IvvkC&printsec=frontcover), page 8 :

> By means of the axioms on intersection and complement, it is possible to prove the existence of a *universal class* $\text V$ and a *null class* $O$.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Unless someone posts a more convincing theory, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

What my professor told me is that V stands for Volk, the German word for people/masses. Since both Zermelo and Fraenkel were German I do not doubt that the "V" stands for the initial letter of a German word, but I cannot provide a solid reference for this version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that it's because of the Von Neumann hierarchy, which tells us that the class of all sets consists of "levels" which are increasing in size, starting with the empty set, so V represents this hierarchy in a way https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe

Comment: I'd argue that someone already gave that answer, and I wrote a comment suggesting some evidence against that, and then they deleted their answer.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't know that... I just saw this question. Yet I think this is a valid argument to answer the OP's question.

Comment: I didn't think you did it on purpose, I was just mentioning a fact you were probably oblivious of. Let me write my comment again, since I feel it's worth repeating.

Comment: Yes, that is a plausible argument, but it is more likely that Mauro's answer is the correct one. I say this because it is also common to use $V$ before introducing the cumulative hierarchy, which is then denoted by $\rm WF$, and then the axiom of regularity is equivalent to $V=\rm WF$. The use of $V$ *outside* of the von Neumann universe as a syntactic symbol therefore can be seen as evidence against your argument. Of course, this could also be "temporary measure until we introduce the axiom of regularity" kind of approach, which is why I say evidence rather carefully.

Comment: In addition to what Asaf said, it would be unusual to use V as the initial for Von Neumann. Prepositions in surnames are usually ignored for that. Compare e.g. NBG where the N is for Von Neumann.

Comment: @HenningMakholm my argument is not related to the fact that Von Neumann contains the letter V, but the fact that the hierarchy is monotone increasing in size, which is why it is described with levels or ranks and every set belongs to exactly one of these levels.